# Запятая или двоеточие? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, выбор-варианта

> Ситуация с образованием на русском языке в Казахстане тоже заметно отличается от других государств бывшей советской Средней **Азии,** в стране 1500 русских школ, а образование на русском языке, как, впрочем, и на английском, считается престижным.

Будет ли ошибкой вставить двоеточие после *"Азии"*? В оригинальном тексте используется именно запятая.

[Кто сегодня в мире говорит по-русски?](https://novostique.ru/kto-segodnia-v-mire-govorit-po-rysski.html)

Comment: Любопытный вопрос. Но, Ольга, на будущее: если даете в вопросе *оригинальный текст*, то оформляйте, пожалуйста, на него ссылку. Так ведь и отвечающим проще — можно посмотреть статью целиком и понять, что из чего следует. Да и тем, кто посещает сайт, удобнее ориентироваться в ответах.

Comment: В следующий раз постараюсь не забыть. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Пояснительное двоеточие** здесь, пожалуй, единственный вариант, так как вторая часть БСП **подробно раскрывает** содержание первой части:

*Ситуация с образованием на русском языке в Казахстане тоже заметно отличается от других государств бывшей советской Средней Азии: в стране 1500 русских школ, а образование на русском языке, как, впрочем, и на английском, считается престижным.*

2. Что касается **запятой**, распространяющей первую тему, то она возможна только в **малораспространенных предложениях**, например:

*Там и отношение к нашей культуре особое,  обучение  на русском языке считается престижным.*

Answer (score 1):

Ошибкой как раз будет оставить запятую. Такое длинное предложение нельзя разграничивать только запятыми: это мешает пониманию.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен по краткой этой цитате знак оценки числа школ, возможно, из-за противопоставления, заложенного во второй части фразы. Предположив, что контекст эту проблему устраняет, можно отнести предложение к типам, о которых говорится у Розенталя, — БСП с ПСО, где равно возможны двоеточие и тире.

> 4. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с
>    причинно-следственными отношениями. Ср.: Последние дни флажки на карте
>    не двигались: положение оставалось без перемен (Сим.)

> 5. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями: Ср. постановку тире вместо ожидаемого
>    двоеточия: В небе выскакивают беленькие точки — рвутся шрапнели
>    (Кат.); С берёз крупными слезами сыплются капли — идут весенние соки
>    (Кат.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие ошибкой не будет, но почему бы не поставить точку?
Предложение и так излишне длинное.
По мне так точка бы выглядела наиболее уместно.

Comment: Нужна ли запятая после "по мне", как считаете?

Comment: @grizzly В устной речи я всю фразу (по мне так) говорю на одном дыхании. Предполагаю, что не обособляется. [Лермонтов, вроде, тоже так считал](https://books.google.com/books?id=SI5yp51b2wgC&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=%22%D0%9F%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&source=bl&ots=hh8bGNYUPP&sig=ACfU3U1OVu_BfoPp5uWuNkmBkr-qk4R5iA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh4t_QsPbyAhVjg-AKHeCIAt0Q6AF6BAgDEAM).

Comment: Согласен, спасибо.